# removing mysql rows from an already filtered query

Tags: mysql

I need 3 different queries from a mysql database table that contains 100,000s of rows. The use case would be "display everything", "display everything removing duplicate 'values', and "display those that only have changed values from the first value queried, within the time range"

### "display everything"

```
mysql> select param_id,time,value  
       from PARAMETERS 
       where param_id like 'point_%' and 
       time >= '2015-352T01:56:52.270' 
       and time <= '2015-360T07:20:32.010' 
       order by param_id,time; 
+----------+-----------------------+------------+
| param_id | time                  | value      |
+----------+-----------------------+------------+
| point_x  | 2015-352T01:56:52.270 | 0.0        |
| point_x  | 2015-360T07:20:32.010 | 1.57       |
| point_x  | 2015-360T07:20:32.010 | 1.57       |
| point_y  | 2015-352T01:56:52.270 | -0.5       |
| point_y  | 2015-352T01:56:55.857 | -0.5       |
| point_y  | 2015-360T07:20:32.010 | -0.5       |
| point_y  | 2015-360T07:20:32.010 | -0.5       |
| point_z  | 2015-352T01:56:52.270 | -9.703     |
| point_z  | 2015-360T07:20:32.010 | 0.0        |
| point_z  | 2015-360T07:20:32.010 | 0.0        |
+----------+-----------------------+------------+
```

### "display everything removing duplicate 'value's per param_id"

```
mysql> select param_id,time,value,count(*) as replicates  
       from PARAMETERS where 
       param_id like 'point_%' and 
       time >= '2015-352T01:56:52.270' and 
       time <= '2015-360T07:20:32.010' 
       group by value,param_id order by param_id,time;
+----------+-----------------------+--------+------------+
| param_id | time                  | value  | replicates |
+----------+-----------------------+--------+------------+
| point_x  | 2015-352T01:56:52.270 | 0.0    |          1 |
| point_x  | 2015-360T07:20:32.010 | 1.57   |          2 |
| point_y  | 2015-352T01:56:55.857 | -0.5   |          4 |
| point_z  | 2015-352T01:56:52.270 | -9.703 |          1 |
| point_z  | 2015-360T07:20:32.010 | 0.0    |          2 |
+----------+-----------------------+--------+------------+
```

### The above queries work great

The last query I'm having issues with is the 
"display everything removing duplicate 'value's per param_id, **in addition to omitting the first 'value'** (this value would be considered default and doesn't need displaying)"

**Question:**
What would the query be that would only omit the 'point_y' row from this query, due to the fact it has only had 1 'value' (-0.5) during this time range?

## Updates

Having count(param_id)>1 doesnt work...

```
mysql> select param_id,time,value,count(*) as replicates  
       from PARAMETERS where  
       param_id like 'point_%' and 
       time >= '2015-352T01:56:52.270' and 
       time <= '2015-360T07:20:32.010' 
       group by value,param_id having count(param_id)>1  
       order by param_id,time;
+----------+-----------------------+-------+------------+
| param_id | time                  | value | replicates |
+----------+-----------------------+-------+------------+
| point_x  | 2015-360T07:20:32.010 | 1.57  |          2 |
| point_y  | 2015-352T01:56:55.857 | -0.5  |          4 |
| point_z  | 2015-360T07:20:32.010 | 0.0   |          2 |
+----------+-----------------------+-------+------------+
```

"having count" within a subselect? No good either...

```
mysql>  select * from (select param_id,time,value  from PARAMETERS where 
                 param_id like 'point_%' and 
                 time >= '2015-352T01:56:52.270' and 
                 time <= '2015-360T07:20:32.010' 
                 group by value,param_id order by param_id,time) as t1 
        having (count(t1.param_id)>1);
+----------+-----------------------+-------+
| param_id | time                  | value |
+----------+-----------------------+-------+
| point_x  | 2015-352T01:56:52.270 | 0.0   |
+----------+-----------------------+-------+
```

## Possible Solution (needs optimizing)

The following join query could work as I can use some serverside code, but it doubles the query time. Is there a way to optimize this?

```
mysql> select t1.param_id,t1.time,t1.value,t2.param_id_cnt 
       from (
          select param_id,time,value 
          from PARAMETERS 
               where param_id like 'point_%' and 
               time >= '2015-352T01:56:52.270' and 
               time <= '2015-360T07:20:32.010' 
               group by param_id, value 
               order by param_id,time ) t1 
       join (
          select *,count(X.param_id) as param_id_cnt 
          from (
               select id,param_id,time,value  
               from PARAMETERS 
                    where param_id like 'point_%' and 
                    time >= '2015-352T01:56:52.270' and 
                    time <= '2015-360T07:20:32.010' 
                    group by param_id, 
                    value order by param_id,time ) X 
               group by X.param_id) t2 
        on t1.param_id=t2.param_id;


+----------+-----------------------+--------+--------------+
| param_id | time                  | value  | param_id_cnt |
+----------+-----------------------+--------+--------------+
| point_x  | 2015-352T01:56:52.270 | 0.0    |            2 |
| point_x  | 2015-360T07:20:32.010 | 1.57   |            2 |
| point_y  | 2015-352T01:56:55.857 | -0.5   |            1 |
| point_z  | 2015-352T01:56:52.270 | -9.703 |            2 |
| point_z  | 2015-360T07:20:32.010 | 0.0    |            2 |
+----------+-----------------------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: Where param_id <> 'point_y' ??

Comment: `having count(param_id) > 1`?

Comment: I don't quite understand why having count(param_id)>1 doesn't work. I've updated the post with the having>1 query results.

Answer (score 0):

First you take only those `param_id` that have more than 1 distinct value from your *"display everything removing duplicate 'value's per param_id"* query and then you join it with that query again for filtered `param_id`.

```
SELECT 
    a.param_id, b.time, b.value
FROM (
    select param_id
    from PARAMETERS 
    where 
       param_id like 'point_%' and 
       time >= '2015-352T01:56:52.270' and 
       time <= '2015-360T07:20:32.010' 
    group by param_id
    having count(distinct value) > 1
    ) a
JOIN (
    select param_id,time,value
    from PARAMETERS 
    where 
       param_id like 'point_%' and 
       time >= '2015-352T01:56:52.270' and 
       time <= '2015-360T07:20:32.010' 
    group by value,param_id order by param_id, time
    ) b ON  
        a.param_id = b.param_id
ORDER BY a.param_id, b.time
```

**Edited after comment:**

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support `WITH` clause which is used to define Common Table Expressions. One way to prevent executing the same query twice would be to create a temporary table and use it inside that query. You can read more about temporary tables in MySQL [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html).

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_parameters AS (
    select param_id,time,value
    from PARAMETERS 
    where 
       param_id like 'point_%' and 
       time >= '2015-352T01:56:52.270' and 
       time <= '2015-360T07:20:32.010' 
    group by value,param_id order by param_id, time
);
```

Adjusted query would look like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.param_id, b.time, b.value
FROM (
    select param_id
    from tmp_parameters
    group by param_id
    having count(distinct value) > 1
    ) a
JOIN tmp_parameters b ON a.param_id = b.param_id
ORDER BY a.param_id, b.time
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very close to my "possible solution" but still requires a long query time. I was looking for a way to save the first query and join it on itself so it wouldn't need to query the same data again, but I haven't found a way.